# How to find out number/name of unicode character in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

In Python:

```
>>> "\N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}"
'♠'
>>> "\u2660"
'♠'
```

Now, let's say I have a character which I don't know the name or number for. Is there a Python function which gives this information like this?

```
>>> wanted_function('♠')
["BLACK SPADE SUIT", "u2660"]
```

Comment: Note: In python2 the `\N{}` escape sequence only works in unicode strings.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You may find the [unicodedata](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) module handy:

```
>>> s = "\N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}"
>>> s
'♠'
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(s)
'BLACK SPADE SUIT'
>>> ord(s)
9824
>>> hex(ord(s))
'0x2660'
```