# Python escape sequence \N{name} not working as per definition

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, unicode-string, python-unicode

I am trying to print unicode characters given their name as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "\N{SOLIDUS}"
print "\N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}"
```

However the output I get is not very encouraging.

The escape sequence is printed as is.

```
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:21:10) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
... print "\N{SOLIDUS}"
\N{SOLIDUS}
>>> print "\N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}"
\N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}
>>>
```

I can however see that [another asker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106175/how-to-find-out-number-name-of-unicode-character-in-python%20another%20asker) has been able to do this successfully.

What's wrong?

Comment: The other question was using python 3, you are 2.7.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Those sequences only work in unicode strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), which is the only kind of string Python 3 has. So in Python 2 you need to prefix the string literal with a `u`.

```
>>> print "\N{SOLIDUS} \N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}"
\N{SOLIDUS} \N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}
>>> print u"\N{SOLIDUS} \N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}"
/ ♠
```

Relevant line from the docs:

> `\N{name}` Character named name in the Unicode database (Unicode only)