# Printing unicode number of chars in a string (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

This should be simple, but I can't crack it.

I have a string of Arabic symbols between `u'\u0600'` - `u'\u06FF'` and `u'\uFB50'` - `u'\uFEFF'`. For example `غينيا واستمر العصبة ضرب قد`.

How do I print each character's unicode number? I'm using Python 2.7.

---

Something like the following gives me `decoding Unicode is not supported`:

```
for c in example_string:
    print unicode(c,'utf-8')
```

Comment: `ord(u'\u06FF')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out number/name of unicode character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106175/how-to-find-out-number-name-of-unicode-character-in-python)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: don't get me wrong, `\u06FF` is what I'm trying to print.

Comment: You want the Python-like representation of the string?

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment you said '`\u06FF` is what I'm trying to print' - this could also be done using Python's `repr` function, although you seem pretty happy with hex(ord(c)). This may be useful for someone looking for a way to find an ascii representation of a unicode character, though.

```
example_string = u'\u063a\u064a\u0646\u064a'

for c in example_string:
    print repr(c), c
```

gives output

```
u'\u063a' غ
u'\u064a' ي
u'\u0646' ن
u'\u064a' ي
```

If you want to strip out the Python unicode literal part, you can quite simply do

```
for c in example_string:
    print repr(c)[2:-1], c
```

to get the output

```
\u063a غ
\u064a ي
\u0646 ن
\u064a ي
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `ord()` function.

```
for c in example_string:
    print(ord(c), hex(ord(c)), c.encode('utf-8'))
```

will give you the decimal, hex codepoint as well as the UTF-8 encoding for this character, like so:

```
(1594, '0x63a', '\xd8\xba')
(1610, '0x64a', '\xd9\x8a')
(1606, '0x646', '\xd9\x86')
(1610, '0x64a', '\xd9\x8a')
(1575, '0x627', '\xd8\xa7')
(32, '0x20', ' ')
  :
  :
```