# how to scrape Bengali character properly with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape Bengali characters properly with python. I already try decode it but it gives me an error and while I encode it give me some non readable things

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


import requests

import urllib3

import requests

import pprint

import json

from requests.models import DecodeError
from urllib3.util.url import Url

content = []

# for i in range(1, 25):
url = 'https://sattacademy.com/job-solution/view?cat_id=1&sub_cat_id=893'

res= requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

anchor = soup.findAll("a", attrs={"class": "nav-link"})


for ref in anchor:

   print(ref.text)
```

This is my output ->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUUWJ.png)

But i want this clealry.Thnx

Comment: Hi, will you send a picture of `ref.text` value?

Comment: @Hamed i send it in my output link plz check it thnx

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you. Shows how to print utf-8 characters in python.

[Printing unicode number of chars in a string (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797769/printing-unicode-number-of-chars-in-a-string-python)

Comment: it didnt work cuz my string is not in this form it didnt decode well enough thats why its gave me output like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUUWJ.png

Comment: after implement it in my code it hit me some decimal number soup = soup.encode('utf-8')
# anchor = soup.findAll("a", attrs={"class": "nav-link"})
for i in soup:
    print(repr(i), i)

Comment: Your output picture in comment and picture in question are the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

content = []
url = 'https://sattacademy.com/job-solution/view?cat_id=1&sub_cat_id=893'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
anchor = soup.findAll("a", attrs={"class": "nav-link"})
for ref in anchor:
    print(ref.text.encode('utf-8'))
```